# Retrofit converts response with null values

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting a null User after logging in with retrofit. This is the response I'm getting:

```
{"status":{"code":0,"message":"Ok."},"result":{"user":{"id":29366,"first_name":"Pinch","last_name":"oijoiji","alias_exists":true}}}
```

But after retrofit parses it I'm getting all the user fields null. Here's the user class:

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class User implements Parcelable {

public static final Parcelable.Creator<User> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<User>() {
    public User createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new User(in);
    }

    @Override
    public User[] newArray(int i) {
        return new User[i];
    }
};
@SerializedName("id")
private String  mId;
@SerializedName("first_name")
private String  mFirstName;
@SerializedName("last_name")
private String  mLastName;
@SerializedName("login")
private String  mEmailAddress;
@SerializedName("msisdn")
private String  mPhoneNumber;
@SerializedName("plate")
private String  mCarRegistrationNumber;
private String  mLanguageCode;
private String  mCountryCode;
@SerializedName("alias_exists")
private boolean mHasBankingInformation;

public User() {

}

public User(Parcel parcel) {
    mId = parcel.readString();
    mFirstName = parcel.readString();
    mLastName = parcel.readString();
    mEmailAddress = parcel.readString();
    mPhoneNumber = parcel.readString();
    mCarRegistrationNumber = parcel.readString();
    mLanguageCode = parcel.readString();
    mCountryCode = parcel.readString();
    mHasBankingInformation = parcel.readByte() == 1;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(mId);
    parcel.writeString(mFirstName);
    parcel.writeString(mLastName);
    parcel.writeString(mEmailAddress);
    parcel.writeString(mPhoneNumber);
    parcel.writeString(mCarRegistrationNumber);
    parcel.writeString(mLanguageCode);
    parcel.writeString(mCountryCode);
    parcel.writeByte((byte) (mHasBankingInformation ? 1 : 0));
}

// Basic methods

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }

    if (!(o instanceof User)) {
        return false;
    }

    User user = (User) o;

    return mId.equals(user.mId);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return mId.hashCode();
}

// Accessors

/**
 * This mId can be used to uniquely identify the user on remote servers.
 *
 * @return User's unique mId.
 */
public String getId() {
    return mId;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.mId = id;
}

/**
 * @return User's first name.
 */
public String getFirstName() {
    return mFirstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.mFirstName = firstName;
}

/**
 * @return User's last name.
 */
public String getLastName() {
    return mLastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.mLastName = lastName;
}

/**
 * @return User's email address.
 */
public String getEmailAddress() {
    return mEmailAddress;
}

public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
    this.mEmailAddress = emailAddress;
}

/**
 * @return User's mobile phone number.
 */
public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return mPhoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.mPhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

/**
 * @return User's car registration number (vehicle plat).
 */
public String getCarRegistrationNumber() {
    return mCarRegistrationNumber;
}

public void setCarRegistrationNumber(String carRegistrationNumber) {
    this.mCarRegistrationNumber = carRegistrationNumber;
}

/**
 * @return User's preferred language ISO code.
 */
public String getLanguageCode() {
    return mLanguageCode;
}

public void setLanguageCode(String languageCode) {
    this.mLanguageCode = languageCode;
}

/**
 * @return User's country ISO code.
 */
public String getCountryCode() {
    return mCountryCode;
}

public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
    this.mCountryCode = countryCode;
}

/**
 * @return Whether the user has defined banking information (credit card) for his account.
 */
public boolean getHasBankingInformation() {
    return mHasBankingInformation;
}

public void setHasBankingInformation(boolean hasBankingInformation) {
    this.mHasBankingInformation = hasBankingInformation;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("User{");
    sb.append("mId='").append(mId).append('\'');
    sb.append(", mFirstName='").append(mFirstName).append('\'');
    sb.append(", mLastName='").append(mLastName).append('\'');
    sb.append(", mEmailAddress='").append(mEmailAddress).append('\'');
    sb.append(", mPhoneNumber='").append(mPhoneNumber).append('\'');
    sb.append(", mCarRegistrationNumber='").append(mCarRegistrationNumber).append('\'');
    sb.append(", mLanguageCode='").append(mLanguageCode).append('\'');
    sb.append(", mCountryCode='").append(mCountryCode).append('\'');
    sb.append(", mHasBankingInformation=").append(mHasBankingInformation);
    sb.append('}');
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

And here's the LoginResponse class:

```
public class LoginResponse extends WebServiceResponse<User> {

@Override
public void setResult(User result) {
    super.setResult(result);
}
```

}

And the WebServiceResponse class:

```
public abstract class WebServiceResponse<T> {
// ===============================================================================
// Member variables
// ===============================================================================


@SerializedName("status")
private Status mStatus;
@SerializedName("result")
private T      mResult;

// ===============================================================================
// Utility methods
// ===============================================================================

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "WebServiceResponse{" +
               "mStatus=" + mStatus +
               ", mResult=" + mResult +
               '}';
}

/**
 * @return Whether the response is valid, based on its status code.
 */
public boolean isValid() {
    // TODO: Use a custom Error class
    return mStatus != null && mStatus.getCode() == 0;
}

// ===============================================================================
// Accessors
// ===============================================================================

public Status getStatus() {
    return mStatus;
}

public void setStatus(Status status) {
    mStatus = status;
}

public T getResult() {
    return mResult;
}

public void setResult(T result) {
    mResult = result;
}

public static class Status {
    // ===============================================================================
    // Member variables
    // ===============================================================================

    @SerializedName("code")
    private int    mCode;
    @SerializedName("message")
    private String mMessage;

    // ===============================================================================
    // Utility methods
    // ===============================================================================

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Status{" +
                   "mCode=" + mCode +
                   ", mMessage='" + mMessage + '\'' +
                   '}';
    }

    // ===============================================================================
    // Accessors
    // ===============================================================================

    public int getCode() {
        return mCode;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        mCode = code;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return mMessage;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        mMessage = message;
    }
}

}
```

And the signIn function is this:

```
public Call<LoginResponse> signIn(final String username, final String password, final ConnectionCallback callback) {
    Call<LoginResponse> call = WebServiceHelper2.getInstance().signIn(username, password);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<LoginResponse> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            if (response.isSuccess()) {
                if (response.body().isValid()) {
                    storeSession(username, password);
                    notifySessionStateChange(true);
                    if (callback != null) {
                        callback.onSuccess(response.body().getResult());
                    }
                } else {
                    callback.onError(response.body().getStatus().getCode());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    return call;
}
```

Any ideas what I'm missing? The response is good but after that the resulted object has all the fields null like I said.

Comment: are you using any Gson builder?

Comment: I'm using GsonConverterFactory if that's what you mean.

Comment: Here it is: Retrofit adapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(createClient())
                .build();

Comment: its most likely because of the generic type T for result, change it to object instead and then cast at runtime

Comment: I have all the requests made that way and that's the only one that does not work properly. I even have an Account class which also has a User object and it reads it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of the generic type T I was using, like Bhargav said. The way it was implemented it was only reading and answer in this form:

```
{"status":{"code":0,"message":"Ok."},"result":{"id":29367,"first_name":"Pinch","last_name":"Test2","alias_exists":true}}
```

But my answer was in this form:

```
{"status":{"code":0,"message":"Ok."},"result":{"user":{"id":29367,"first_name":"Pinch","last_name":"Test2","alias_exists":true}}}
```

I've made a UserParent class like so:

```
public class UserParent implements Parcelable {
@SerializedName("user")
private User user;


protected UserParent(Parcel in) {
    user = in.readParcelable(User.class.getClassLoader());
}

public static final Creator<UserParent> CREATOR = new Creator<UserParent>() {
    @Override
    public UserParent createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new UserParent(in);
    }

    @Override
    public UserParent[] newArray(int size) {
        return new UserParent[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeParcelable(user, flags);
}

public User getChild() {
    return user;
}
```

}

And I implemented it like this:

```
public class LoginResponse extends WebServiceResponse<UserParent> {

@Override
public void setResult(UserParent result) {
    super.setResult(result);
}

@Override
public UserParent getResult() {
    return super.getResult();
}
```

}